# How to do transition of android videoplayer from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions, android-video-player

I am making a IPTV app and want to play video by single object.Firstly Video play on activity and when user click on it it should play in fragment with small size.look [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbYZzQywzrI) video from 3:40. I want like this.

Comment: Like youtube does?

Comment: No I have shared one video link. I want like that.

Comment: You can change dimensions of player to full height width using _DisplayMetrics_ when click for full screen in same activity i think